# Intel Compute Stick, move Ubuntu OS to SanDisk microdrive

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, computestick

Recently bought the Intel Compute Stick, like it a lot. Meets the need in many ways.

I would like to move the Ubuntu 14.04 to a 64GB SanDisk microdrive, and reallocate the 5GB of remaining internal HD space to Swap.

My preference would be to install from the recovery to the microdrive, or to copy Ubuntu to the microdrive. Have tried downloading 15.10, but it is not as nicely configured as the 14.04 on the recovery.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to perform a restore from the PQService, but it only does this on the internal HD, gives no option to perform a backup to another hard drive location.
Also attempted to perform a backup, but there does not seem to be a valid backup tool for 14.04.
Finally seems the only option is to install from a fresh download to the new Sandisk, and to set that in BIOS as the main drive.